# Does Belgium or its inhabitants have any roles of note in DC or Marvel?

Tags: marvel, dc

As a Belgian myself, i sometimes wonder if Belgium is only known for their chocolates, fries and beer, or if Belgium has a significant presence in DC or Marvel comics outside of those (delicious) consumables.

I know that Doctor Evil from Austin Powers was raised in Belgium, but I'm surprised that I don't have any knowledge of a significant role for Belgium or the Belgian people in DC or Marvel comics. Is there a Belgian superhero or supervillain? Is there a story arc that mostly occurs in Belgium?

Comment: Have you tried searching for keyword 'Belgium' on the Marvel wikia ?  It returns several references.  Might not be extremely noteworthy, but they exist.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even know there was a Marvel wikia.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Paul. I misunderstood certain parts from the 3rd film and thought they were both born in Belgium.

Comment: They make the waffles that keep Tony Stark from simply rolling over and staying in bed every morning. Who knows how many lives those stalwart Belgians have saved?

Comment: As a Brit, I can assure you that Belgium isn't known for its fries. Waffles, yes, Sprouts, yes, fries, no.

Comment: The Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy references Belgium, although not relevant to the question as such I thought I would mention it for interests sake.

Comment: @Richard You have OBVIOUSLY never been to an authentic Belgian friterie. Let me tell you, Belgian fries are some of the best in the world. Not the frozen variety, but the freshly peeled, sliced and baked ones from an authentic friterie. [Friteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friterie) have their own wikipedia article, and [fries are a separate item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuisine_of_Belgium#Fries) of the Cuisine of Belgium article.

Comment: @nate.kerkhofs - there's a lot of difference between what you think you're famous for vs what you're actually famous for.

Comment: @Richard I don't want to bring this too off-topic, but googling "what is Belgium famous for" has most websites at least mention French Fries, usually with the explanation why they're called French Fries instead of Belgian Fries.

Comment: It's not a scientific test, but I've just asked my eight work colleagues what foods Belgium is famous for. Chocolates = 7, sprouts =5, waffles = 4, Seafood =1, fries = 0

Comment: @Richard At this point, we both have rather unscientific methods of figuring out the fame of the fries. Let's just agree to disagree on this. Or maybe one of us should ask the question on Seasoned Advice.SE or Travel.SE.

Comment: That's true. One of them said that Belgium was famous for Danish pastries so I'm willing to admit that it's not a perfect measure.

Comment: As an American I feel it's my patriotic duty to inject my own unsolicited opinion which I will then think is the most valid, because as I've previously stated I'm an American. While I'm familiar with Belgian Friteries, I think what most people would associate Belgium with cuisine wise would be the waffle and chocolate. I must now ride an eagle in to the sunset and spread my (unwanted) patriotism to the rest of the masses. Merica!!!

Comment: @Stefan but it's not a word used in polite conversation!

Comment: @liath I believe it might be used in one place but only because they have no idea what it means

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there are. Search the [Marvel Wikia for Belgium-related keywords](http://marvel.wikia.com/Special:Search?search=belgium&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns116=1&ns118=1). E.g., there's a [Wolverine issue](http://marvel.wikia.com/Marvel_Comics_Presents_Vol_1_87#Appearing_in_.22Just_Friends_.28Part_3.29_-_If_This_is_Tuesday.2C_It_Must_Be_Belgium.22) that has Belgium in its title.

Wolverine and Daken [have a bloody fight in Brussels](http://marvel.wikia.com/Akihiro_(Earth-616)) (see 'Meeting Wolverine').

[Searching for 'Belgian'](http://marvel.wikia.com/Special:Search?search=belgian&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns116=1&ns118=1#) reveals that Klaw has the Belgian citizenship.

I'm not familiar with DC Comics, but they also have their own Wikia. [Check out the appearances for Belgium](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Belgium/Appearances).

Not comic-canon, but in "[A Fractured House](http://agentsofshield.wikia.com/wiki/A_Fractured_House)" (S02E06) of Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., a Belgian minister is featured and the safe house is located in Belgium.

Answer (score 1):

The official Marvel Atlas lists three characters from Belgium:

- [Rem-Ram](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix6/rem-ramacolyte.htm), a minor X-Men villain
- [Commander Courage](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix/comcor.htm), another villain
- [The Belgian Brain](http://www.marvunapp.com/Appendix2/shesentry.htm#belgianbrain), Belgium's representative at the Super Heroes of Europe

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of belgian characters in the marvel comics. 3 members of the klaw (klaue) family, famous of their hate for black panther and the vibranium. There is an Belgian mutant who is actually one of the strongest there has ever been: Mister M or Absolon Mercator. Belgian is also sometimes referred to in the WWII comics. for more info about these characters, look them up on marvel wikia :) (im belgian myself so i was also very interested)

Answer (score 1):

In Marvel's Ultimate Universe, we had a supervillain that's raised in Belgium named Victor Van Damme AKA Doctor Doom.

(In the main Marvel universe, Victor Von Doom was born in the fictitious country of Latveria).